# Telekinetic Psychic powers - Do they ignore armor/TB?

Tags: rogue-trader

For example, Telekinetic crush (other powers already specify they work like regular projectiles)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the wording of that ability and the wording of Telekinetic Weapon, I would say both the armour and TB **do** come in to effect.

The wording of Telekinetic weapon (Core Rules, pg 171-172) explicity states that the weapon has a Penetration value equal to the psykers Psy rating, so by extension, it would mean that the armour value does come in to play when using Psychic powers, unless explicitly stated otherwise.